# How to store the sum of a column from a mysql database to a python variable?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

Kinda long code by complete beginner ahead, please help out

I have a database with the following values:

| Sl.No | trips | sales | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 20 | 220 |
| 2 | 8 | 30 | 330 |
| 3 | 9 | 45 | 440 |
| 4 | 3 | 38 | 880 |

I am trying to use mysql-connector and python to get the sum of the columns trips, sales and price as variables and use it to do some calculations in the python script.
This is what I have so far:

```
def sum_fun():

    try:
        con = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
        database='twitterdb', user='root', password='mypasword', charset='utf8')

        if con.is_connected():
            cursor = con.cursor(buffered=True)
            def sumTrips():
                cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(trips) FROM table_name")
                sum1=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
                return int(sum1)
            def sumSales():
                cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(sales) FROM table_name")
                sum2=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
                return int(sum2)
            def sumPrice():
                cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(price) FROM table_name")
                sum3=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
                return int(sum3)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    cursor.close()
    con.close()
```

I would like to receive the the three sums as three variables `sum_trips`, `sum_sales` and `sum_price` and assign a point system for them such that:

```
trip_points=20*sum_trips
sales_points=30*sum_sales
price_points=40*sum_price
```

And then take the three variables `trip_points, sales_points, prices_points` and insert it into another table in the same database named `Points` with the column names same as variable names.

**I have been trying so hard to find an answer to this for so long. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. I am a total beginner to most of this stuff so if there's a better way to achieve what I am looking for please do let me know. Thanks**

Comment: "*I have been trying so hard to find an answer to this for so long*" An answer to *what*, exactly? There doesn't seem to be a clear question or problem statement here - see [ask].

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do this in one shot? `SELECT SUM(trips), SUM(sales), SUM(price) FROM table_name`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something, but Running 3 different queries against the same table (that too in MySQL which is not columnar) is not very efficient, I would probably just execute the following:

```
CREATE new_table as 
(SELECT 
        SUM(trips) * 20 as trip_points,
        SUM(sales) * 20 as sales_points,
        SUM(price) * 20 as price_points
FROM table_name)
```

either on MySQL prompt or from Python (if you are attempting some kind of automation)

Let me know if this helps you move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code, with minor changes that returns a tuple with the three values like `(sumTrips, sumSales, sumPrice)` but I omitted to close the connection intentionally, (see the second code sniped where the connection gets closed automatically):

```
def sum_fun():
    def sumTrips(cursor):  # receives the cursor object, for queries
        cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(trips) FROM table_name")
        sum1=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
        return int(sum1)
    def sumSales(cursor):
        cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(sales) FROM table_name")
        sum2=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
        return int(sum2)
    def sumPrice(cursor):
        cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(price) FROM table_name")
        sum3=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
        return int(sum3)
    
    try:
        con = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', password='mypasword',
                                      database='twitterdb', user='root',  charset='utf8')
        cursor = con.cursor(buffered=True)
        return (sumTrips(cursor), sumSales(cursor), sumPrice(cursor))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise Exception("The connection fail because of this error: {}".format(e))
```

You may want to invoke it as:

```
sumTrips, sumSales, sumPrice = sum_fun()
```

And this code gives the same results but uses `with`:

```
def sum_fun():
    def sum_column(cursor, column):
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT SUM({column}) FROM table_name")
        sum1=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
        return int(sum1)
    
    try:
        with mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', password='mypasword',
                                     database='twitterdb', user='root',  charset='utf8') as con:
            with con.cursor(buffered=True) as cursor:
                return (sum_column(cursor, "trips"), sum_column(cursor, "sales"), sum_column(cursor, "price"))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise Exception("The connection fail because of this error: {}".format(e))
```

The code above code uses `with` statement, it will close the connection when the block in `with` finish, because invokes the `__exit__()` method which calls `close()` method to close the connection.